# How to prevent access to Firebase Realtime Database from browser console?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this JavaScript code where users sign in to my app using their google account.

```
//firebase db congifurations
const config = {
  apiKey: "my_api_key",
  authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "my-app",
  databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
};

//signin callback implemented using - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

  let fullName = profile.getName().split(" "); 
  let userName = profile.getEmail().replace(/@.*$/, "");

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
  this.database = firebase.database();

  let userRef = this.database.ref("users/" + userName);
  userRef.set({
    firstName: fullName[0],
    lastName: fullName[1],
    displayPicture: profile.getImageUrl(),
  });
}
```

When I execute this code, put a debugger at `let userRef = this.database.ref("users/" + userName);` and try to run this on console:

```
 userRef.set({
    firstName: "Clutch",
    lastName: "Prince",
    displayPicture: "any_url_that_i_want_to_inject",
  });
```

This one actually gets executed and my database gets affected. Is there a secure way of doing this?

My Realtime Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your database rules..

Comment: Ok, so now tell. Who do want to edit your database? All the users or only you?

Comment: What's the difference between that code that they can write on the console, and them entering the same information in the form? In other words: *what* are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen looks like he does not want any unwanted guests to edit his database. He has set his rules to TRUE so need to modify that  . . .

Comment: @Dharmaraj I want new users to get created by pressing the signin with google button. I don't want some random person doing database edits from console.

Comment: @ClutchPrince Then you might need to go other way around. You fine with Cloud functions?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, anything that will protect this.

Comment: @ClutchPrince I meant do you know how to code Cloud Function? Then I'll just say what to do and you can code peacefully :-)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213030/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-clutch-prince).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase rules are the most important part.
No one except you can edit those. So make sure they are secure. You have `.write: true` means anyone can write your database. 
To prevent that you should have secure rules. You can check out [this link](https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6) for most of the rules combinations.

Looking at your issue, set the rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you store all the users data in different nodes. Keep the node value as their UID. Then the above rules should be handy

Now users can edit or read only their information. Even if they try to edit it via console, atleast you are keeping others safe. 
If it's a game, sure go ahead and add penalty if you spot them XD.

This can still allow users to edit atleast their information as stated earlier as well. So in case if you are storing some sort of a game statistics and how much resources the player has, then you need to block write access by doing this:
`".write": false`

Now this might confuse you that if write access is denied then how will players update their scores or how can one add the username in database.

For this, you need to rely on cloud functions. Whenever a new player creates an account, I run a cloud function which adds default level and other stuff. Here a code sample below:

```
export const onNewuserJoined = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const newUserUID = user.uid
    const newUserEmail = user.email

    return Promise.all([
    admin.database().ref(player_stats_path).set({ "Level": initLevel, "Cash": initCash}),
    admin.database().ref(player_info_path).set({ "UID": newUserUID, "E-Mail": newUserEmail})
    ])
})
```

Now these `player_stats_path` and `player_info_path` will have read access only so no one can mess with it except for the cloud functions as the **OVERRIDE** any rules present. If you need to change the stats of someone when they complete a particular task or so, you will need to do it via cloud functions only. It's nice to have all game code in backend.

Comment: Your rules don't define a `$uid` node anywhere, so the check is pretty meaningless right now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I had explained him in the discussion in chat. I'll include that in my answer . Thanks for spotting :-)

Comment: Thanks for that update. These rules require that the user has signed in with Firebase Authentication, and that they can only write data under their own UID. It does not prevent what data they actually write, which is what the original question seemed to be about.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as far as our discussions went, I had asked if he needed more information. I'll keep updating this answer with all possibilities as soon as I know. For know, I'm thinking of tranferring the data to a read only node when registration is done or modify the data if needed using cloud functions. I'll also wait for the asker if he has any specific case again