# Firestore rules: Prevent overwrite of property

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestor rules, how can I allow new documents to be created to a collection, and new values to be added to a document but not values in the document to be overwritten?

Please see the following for a clearer understanding:

**Collections -------------- Documents -------------- Values**

Users -------------------- DonutCoder -------------- isAdmin, birthDate

Now, if I want to add email to the values under the document Donut Coder how can I do this but prevent overwriting (eg. changing isAdmin to true so the user gets more priveleges)

What I have tried: `allow read, create`    - but this allows new documents to be created but no properties in the document to be changed.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself yet, but you should be able to do something with these new map operations in security rules: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020

Comment: sorry that did not work

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific client code that you would like to allow in this case.  You can probably use the new [MapDiff](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) APIs to detect and allow this.  If you wrote a rule and it didn't work, please edit the question to also show what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

1) Don't add any code that overwrites the same path.

2) TO prevent others from reverse-engineering and update it, add this:

```
allow update: if false
```

Again anyone can still attempt to create the same document again so you need to add more security rules to it. Do check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) for that.

I have answers regarding similar questions but they refer to realtime database. Though you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577948/13130697).

The `allow update: if false` just prevent updating the existing value.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply. Unfortunately that stops me from writing as well.

Comment: I need to be able to add new properties but not change or delete old properties

Comment: @DonutCoder you want to create new properties in the same document?

Comment: @DonutCoder you should keep the allow write: if true

Comment: hi: this is what i have: allow read
      allow write: if true
      allow update: if false and it allows me to read write and update

Comment: @DonutCoder thats because update if form of write... then you need to false the write also... allow create: if true

Answer (score 2):

This official documentation page seems to show how to do this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#preventing_some_fields_from_being_changed

```
allow update: if (!request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(['average_score', 'rating_count']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Preventing isAdmin or birthDate being updated:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.isAdmin = resource.data.isAdmin
  && request.resource.data.birthDate = resource.data.birthDate;
```

You can start building on this depending on your needs. For instance, if you want to allow only logged in user and modifying only one field at a time:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
  && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().size() == 1 
  && request.resource.data.isAdmin = resource.data.isAdmin
  && request.resource.data.birthDate = resource.data.birthDate;
```